# Why does g++ still require -latomic

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, libstdc++, stdatomic

In *29.5 Atomic types* of the C++ Standard November 2014 working draft it states:

> 1. There is a generic class template atomic. The type of the template argument T shall be trivially copyable (3.9). [ Note: Type arguments that are not also statically initializable may be difficult to use. —end note ]

So - as far as I can tell - this:

```
#include <atomic>

struct Message {
    unsigned long int a;
    unsigned long int b;
};

std::atomic<Message> sharedState;

int main() {    
    Message tmp{1,2};       
    sharedState.store(tmp);         
    Message tmp2=sharedState.load();
}
```

should be perfectly valid standard c++14 (and also c++11) code. However, if I don't link `libatomic` manually, the command

```
g++ -std=c++14 <filename>
```

gives - at least on Fedora 22 (gcc 5.1) - the following linking error:

```
/tmp/ccdiWWQi.o: In function `std::atomic<Message>::store(Message, std::memory_order)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicI7MessageE5storeES0_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicI7MessageE5storeES0_St12memory_order]+0x3f): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
/tmp/ccdiWWQi.o: In function `std::atomic<Message>::load(std::memory_order) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI7MessageE4loadESt12memory_order[_ZNKSt6atomicI7MessageE4loadESt12memory_order]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I write

```
g++ -std=c++14 -latomic <filename>
```

everything is fine. 
I know that the standard doesn't say anything about compiler flags or libraries that have to be included, but so far I thought that any standard conformant, single file code can be compiled via the first command.

So why doesn't that apply to my example code? Is there a rational why `-latomic` is still necessary, or is it just something that hasn't been addressed by the compiler maintainers, yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Relevant reading](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/LIbrary) on the GCC homepage on how and why GCC makes library calls in certain cases regarding `<atomic>` in the first place.

GCC and libstdc++ are only losely coupled. `libatomic` is the domain of the library, not the compiler -- and you can use GCC with a different library (which might provide the necessary definitions for `<atomic>` in its main proper, or under a different name), so GCC cannot just *assume* `-latomic`.

[Also](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM):

> GCC 4.7 does not include a library implementation as the API has not been firmly established.

The same page claims that GCC 4.8 shall provide such a library implementation, but plans are the first victims of war. I'd guess the reason for `-latomic` still being necessary can be found in that vicinity.

Besides...

> ...so far I thought that any standard conformant, single file code can be compiled via the first command.

...`-lm` has been around for quite some time if you're using math functions.

Comment: Note that the C++ Standard is somewhat ambiguous whether the library is a separate component - the library sections are fairly standalone, but "the implementation" in standardese means the combination of compiler and library.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but gcc DOES - by default - include a couple of libraries, so how would a default `-latomic` be different?

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but in the case of GCC, "the implementation" means "GCC and some compatible standard library". That's what I wanted to point at -- a not-yet-finalized API between the compiler and *one* of its (n) standard libraries, and you get a separate `-latomic` from the compiler people that didn't think it all that problematic to require a `-lm` for math code either. No big deal, all around.

Comment: I haven't used gcc in a long while,  but for g++  -lm isn't necessary is it?

Comment: Btw: Your Quote about gcc 4.7 was the reason I was asking, why it's STILL necessary in GCC 5.1.

Comment: @MikeMB: Can't really say (with regards to `-lm`) because I haven't used `<math>` in a long while. ;-)

Comment: @MikeMB: I'm using GCC both as a native compiler and as a cross-compiler for multiple arm-linux platforms (hard and soft FP). In none of those, I need an `-lm` with `g++`, and my code is math-heavy enough to warrant a `-fpmath=sse`.

Comment: The comparison with `-lm` is really wrong. libm is provided by libc (at least on most *nix platforms), and so is meaningful for most of the compilers. libatomic is an internal gcc library that is needed on some arches for some cases of atomics, for some gcc versions (and clang with -rtlib=libgcc). In other words, adding `-lm` is usually safe, adding `-latomic` is pretty much a guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the standard doesn't say anything about compiler flags or libraries that have to be included

Right.

> but so far I thought that any standard conformant, single file code can be compiled via the first command.

Well, no. As you *just* said, there is no particular reason to assume this. Consider also that GCC extensions are enabled by default.

That being said, it seems self-evident that the intention is to make `-latomic` a default part of the runtime when it's settled down a bit.

Comment: Obviously I didn't make that assumption based on anything written in the standard, but based on my(somewhat limited) experience with g++. Also correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `-std=c++11` disable g++ specific extensions?

Comment: @MikeMB: Oh, it might.

Comment: Continuing to require `-latomic` explicitly is a good way to detect use of non-lock-free atomics, on platforms where lock-free atomics can inline.  (Sometimes this requires `-march=native` or something else to enable an ISA extension, or for ARM a `-mcpu=` setting to enable it.)

Answer (score -4):

`g++` is a wrapper for `gcc` which adds the correct C++ libraries. Clearly `-latomic` is missing from that list. Not a core compiler problem then, simply a minor bug in the wrapper.

Comment: It might well be a conscious decision as it is not fully implemented yet. In particular *29.3 Order and consistency* support is listed as Partial. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014

Comment: `g++` is _not_ "a wrapper for `gcc`". They're more like siblings, both wrapping the various actual compilers (e.g. `cc1plus`).